# Cómo ordenar lista de objetos de una clase de creación propia

Tags: python, poo, lista, objeto, ordenamiento

necesito ordenar una lista de objetos definidos por mí mismo.
El objeto es:

```
class Jugador():

def __init__(self,nombre,puntaje):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.puntuacion = puntaje
```

Y el método ordenar debería simular un insertar ordenado de un array. Eso lo hice. Intenté después implementar el sorted, pero necesita una clave de ordenamiento. Entiendo que es puntacion.. la cuestión es que estoy trabado

```
def agregar(self,jug): 
    '''
    Recibe un jugador y evalúa si su puntuación es mayor a las guardadas. Produce el desplazamiento y elimina a la posición 11
    '''  
    self.puntajes.append(jug)
    sorted (self.puntajes, key=jug.puntuacion)
    self.puntajes.reverse()
    self.puntajes.pop()
```

Debería recibir a jug que es de tipo Jugador. Insertarlo en la lista. Ordenar de mayor a menor (bajo el criterio de puntuacion) y eliminar el último elemento.

Es python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, `sorted` no realiza el ordenamiento in-place, genera una nueva lista ordenada a partir del iterable pasado como argumento y la retorna (en tu ejemplo no capturas el retorno de `sorted` por lo que es como si nada hicieras). Si quieres hacerlo in-place debes usar `list.sort`.

En vez de invertir la lista puedes eliminar el primer item de la misma (`self.puntajes.pop(0)` o `del self.puntajes[0]`) o directamente usar el argumento `reverse=True` de `sorted`/`list.sort`.

Luego, a `key` le pasas siempre el mismo objeto, el valor del atributo puntuación de la instancia `jug`.  El argumento `key` de `sorted`/`list.sort` espera un objeto "llamable" , luego pasa **cada item de la lista** a dicho objeto y usa el retorno para ordenar.

### Usar una función lambda

```
self.puntajes.sort(key=lambda jugador: jugador.puntuacion)
```

### Usar `operator.attrgetter`

```
self.puntajes.sort(key=operator.attrgetter("puntuacion")
```

Es más eficiente que la función.

### Implementar el orden directamente en la clase `Jugador`

Ésto se hace implementando los conocidos como "rich comparison methods" del [modelo de datos de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__). No necesitas implementarlos todos para que funcione, pero es buena práctica hacerlo, en éste caso solo implementaré `__eq__` (operador `==`) y `__lt__` (operador `<`) y el resto se los dejo a `functools.total_ordering`.

```
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Jugador:
    
    def __init__(self, nombre, puntaje):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.puntuacion = puntaje

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.puntuacion == other.puntuacion
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.puntuacion < other.puntuacion
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"{self.__class__.__name__}"
                f"({repr(self.nombre)}, {repr(self.puntuacion)})")
```

Luego simplemente:

```
self.puntajes.sort()
```

Por ejemplo:

> ```
> >>> puntajes = [
>         Jugador("a", 15),
>         Jugador("b", 145), 
>         Jugador("c", 10), 
>         Jugador("d", 15)
>         ]
>     
> >>> puntajes
> [Jugador('a', 15), Jugador('b', 145), Jugador('c', 10), Jugador('d', 15)]
>
> >>> puntajes.sort()
> >>> puntajes
> [Jugador('c', 10), Jugador('a', 15), Jugador('d', 15), Jugador('b', 145)]
>
> >>> puntajes.sort(reverse=True)
> >>> puntajes
> [Jugador('b', 145), Jugador('a', 15), Jugador('d', 15), Jugador('c', 10)]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Ésta no puede ser tenida por respuesta, ya que requiere una versión de python 3.7 o superior**. Pero puede servir por si alguien vé esta pregunta en el futuro.

A partir de la versión 3.7 de python existen las **dataclasses** que hacen más sencillo el manejo de estructura de datos de este tipo. Completando la respuesta que ha dado @FJSevilla, con *dataclasses* se crean automáticamente algunos de los métodos necesarios para hacer comparaciones y ordenaciones.

De este modo, el problema se podría codificar así:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
@dataclass 
class Jugador:

    nombre: str 
    puntuacion: int 
    
    def __lt__(self, other): 
        return self.puntuacion < other.puntuacion
```

Por defecto, la clase de datos `Jugador` tendrá creados los métodos `__init__`, `__repr__` y `__eq__`. Se puede pedir que *dataclass* cree el resto de métodos de ordenación, pero el orden seguiría el orden en que hemos definido los campos: primero por nombre y luego por puntuación.

Como queremos que ordene por puntuación, aplicamos la misma estrategia que en la respuesta de @FJSevilla: usar el decorador `total_ordering` para que genere el resto de métodos a partir de `__eq__`, creado por *dataclass*, y `__lt__`, que hemos creado nosotros.

Podemos comprobar su funcionamiento:

```py
>>> puntaje = [Jugador("a",15),Jugador("b",145),Jugador("c",10),Jugador("d",15)]  
[Jugador(nombre='a', puntuacion=15),
 Jugador(nombre='b', puntuacion=145),
 Jugador(nombre='c', puntuacion=10),
 Jugador(nombre='d', puntuacion=15)]

>>> sorted(puntaje)
[Jugador(nombre='c', puntuacion=10),
 Jugador(nombre='a', puntuacion=15),
 Jugador(nombre='d', puntuacion=15),
 Jugador(nombre='b', puntuacion=145)]

>>> sorted(puntaje, reverse=True)
[Jugador(nombre='b', puntuacion=145),
 Jugador(nombre='a', puntuacion=15),
 Jugador(nombre='d', puntuacion=15),
 Jugador(nombre='c', puntuacion=10)]
```